# Redirect problems with django form in a modal

Tags: python, html, jquery, django, forms

I am trying to implement a form in a modal which is focused on modifying a comment in a post, the way i did it everything works, the problem is when I click on the submit button it sends me to the html in which I have the modal and there I edit the comment. when I try to delete the url in the action form that takes me to the second page of my form it throws the error "local variable 'form' referenced before assign", also if I put for example in form action the url of the login sends me towards There but the comment is not updated or edited.

My idea is simply that when I submitting the form, the modal closes, and the page where the modal was opened from the beginning, reload or simply the comment already edited appears.

if you need more information I can add it.

views.py

```
@need_analyst_role
def comment_modify(request, comment_id):

    if 'comment_edit' in request.POST:
        form_comment = FormComment(request.POST)
        if form_comment.is_valid():
            comment_text = form_comment.cleaned_data['text']
            comment = ModelRiskTracking.objects.get(id=comment_id)
            comment.comment = comment_text
            print(comment.comment)
            comment.save()

        else:
            messages.error(request, 'Error!', extra_tags="danger")
   
    context = {}
    context['comment'] = ModelRiskTracking.objects.get(id=comment_id)
    
    return render(request, 'analyst_pages/comment_edit.html', context = context)
```

modal.html

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h2 class="modal-title">Editar comentario</h2>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <form action="{% url 'soc_irisk_modify' comment_id=comment.id %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <textarea type="text" name="text" class="form-control" rows="15">{{ comment.comment|safe }}</textarea>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" value="Actualizar" name="comment_edit" onsubmit="setFormSubmitting()" class="btn btn-info btn-sm pull-right" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

I open the modal with a button calling a jQuery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openModal(url){
        $('#commentModal').load(url, function(){
            $(this).modal('show');
        });
    }
</script>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#commentModal" onclick="openModal('{% url 'soc_comment_modify' comment_id=comment.id %}')">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you saving the model, you need to redirect the user

```
@need_analyst_role
def comment_modify(request, comment_id):

    if 'comment_edit' in request.POST:
    form_comment = FormComment(request.POST)
    if form_comment.is_valid():
        comment_text = form_comment.cleaned_data['text']
        comment = ModelRiskTracking.objects.get(id=comment_id)
        comment.comment = comment_text
        print(comment.comment)
        comment.save()
        return redirect("some_url")

    else:
        messages.error(request, 'Error!', extra_tags="danger")
        return redirect("some_url")

context = {}
context['comment'] = ModelRiskTracking.objects.get(id=comment_id)

return render(request, 'analyst_pages/comment_edit.html', context = context)
```

Comment: it worked, I had tried before with "return HttpResponseRedirect" that I read in another answer but it didn't work, apparently it was simpler than that, thank you very much for your answer and time !!